# How to concatenate string to -print in unix find command?

Tags: bash, unix, find

I have this command to run in Unix machine where I'm deleting all directories from specific folder if they are older then 1 day:

```
find /path_with_dirs_to_delete/* -type d -mtime +1 -prune -exec rm -rf {} + -print
```

It's currently printing out the folder names and i want to concatenate to the printing output the text " was deleted successfully".
How can I do that?

Comment: How do you know that it was deleted successfull? `rm` could fail. Wouldn't it make more sense to simply do a `rm -rvf` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If using GNU tools, a superior solution is to add the `-v` (verbose) flag to `rm`.

For a POSIX solution you could do this:

```
find /path/* -type d -mtime +1 -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; -exec echo {} was deleted successfully \;
```

- You were running a single `rm` to remove multiple directories. But if you want to test `rm`'s success for each directory, it has to run once per directory (note `;` instead of `+`). Note that this a bit less efficient.
- `-a` ("and") is implied between find actions, meaning the second `-exec` action (`echo`) only runs if the previous one (`rm`) succeds. So this can be used to log a successful removal.
- You will receive an error message from `rm` if a removal fails (eg. permission denied).
- `rm -f` suppresses "does not exist" errors, *and* you wouldn't get a success message either, however `find` won't pass a non-existent directory.